# Express middleware (multer) in seperate file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I was able to move a very simple middleware (isAuthenticated) over to an external middleware file, but I'm having a harder time with moving my multer upload over. I just learned how to move them to seperate files, so it's probably obvius.

```
routes/index.js
var middleware = require('../middleware/common');
var isAuthenticated = middleware.isAuthenticated;
var upload = middleware.multerSetup;
...

router.post('/updateuser',
    upload,
...,
    function (req, res, next) {
        res.redirect('/dashboard');
    }
);
```

--

```
//middleware/common.js
var multer = require('multer');


Middleware = {
        //Checks whether user is logged in
    isAuthenticated: function(req,res,next){
            if(req.isAuthenticated()){
                return next();
            }
            req.flash('auth',"You do not have the proper permissions to access this page");
            res.redirect('/');
        },
    multerSetup: function(req,res,next){
        var storage = multer.diskStorage({
            destination: function (req, file, cb) {
                cb(null, './public/uploads/')
            },
            //detects file type, then adds extension to match file type
            filename: function (req, file, cb) {
                var ext = "";
                switch(file.mimetype){
                    case 'image/png':
                        ext = '.png';
                        break;
                    case 'image/jpeg':
                        ext = '.jpeg';
                        break;
                    default:
                        ext = '';
                }
                cb(null, Date.now() + ext); //Appending .jpg
            }
        });


        var upload = multer({storage:storage, fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
            var acceptedExt = ['.png','.jpg','.gif','.bmp'];
            if (req.hasOwnProperty('file') && acceptedExt.indexOf(path.extname(file.originalname))=== -1) {
                return cb(new Error('Image type not allowed: ' + path.extname(file.originalname)));
            }

            cb(null, true)
        }});

        return upload.single('upl');
     }

};

module.exports = Middleware;
```

Error:

```
routes\index.js:108
    upload.single('upl'), 
           ^

TypeError: upload.single is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Tyler\WebstormProjects\volunteer\volunteerApp\routes\index.js:108:12)
```

Comment: What's the error or problem you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

You're setting up your multer middleware wrong. Your `Middleware.multerSetup` is a middleware function, which is then calling `upload.single` to set up multer (which is then never called and the request is left hanging). Move your multer upload setup outside your custom middleware and have your module export just the return function from `upload.single`.

Example:

```
Middleware = {
   ...
   multerSetup: upload.single('upl')
   ...
}
```

Comment: I know that everyone advocates using a different file to do every little thing. I am allowing my file tree to expand slowly so that I have enough content in each to work, but not so much that it gets messy.

Comment: You don't need to move your multer upload setup to a separate file. Just move it outside your custom middleware function in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Just needed to define upload in routes/index.js as a function.

```
var upload = middleware.multerSetup();
```

Answer (score 0):

Brother in the separate file, declare your setup function, then your middleware and export it, and pass the "file" as a parameter in upload function and return upload.single(file):

```
const multer = require("multer");

function multerSetup() {
  const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, "images");
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, file.originalname);
    },
  });
  return storage;
}

Middleware = {
  upload: function (file) {
    const upload = multer({ storage: multerSetup() });
    return upload.single(file);
  },
};

module.exports = Middleware;
```

In your route file write your route:

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const Middleware = require("../helper/uploadImages");

router.post("/", Middleware.upload("file"), (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json("file has been uploaded!");
});

module.exports = router
```

in index.js file just you need to import your route and use it:

```
const uploadImageRoute = require("./routes/uploadImages");
app.use("/api/upload", uploadImageRoute);
```